# iOS: setAllowsEditing only for video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `UIImagePickerController` with:

```
[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];`
```

`picker.mediaTypes` is set to `kUTTypeMovie` and `kUTTypeImage`

But I would like to set this option only for movies and not for images. How can I implement this?

Comment: Please, in the future, refrain from putting signatures in your posts as outlined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make two sperate buttons(action) for movie and image. when the user wants to capture image disable the editing. Or, I would go with 
[Fully-Customized Media Capture and Browsing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) which will enable you to do many flexible  things

EDIT: Also 'cameraOverlayView' can help. you make a custom view where you make button to handle the event.